# Lookup table with weak references in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lookup, weak-references, lookup-tables

I have a tree structure with elements dynamically added and removed. The elements are loaded dynamically from the network. What I want to achieve is to have a lookup table that maps the element's id to the actual element in the tree. Now, the problem when using a simple Map or Object is that it holds strong references to the tree elements which will bloat the memory after a while. Since node >= 14.6.0 and Chrome >= 84 [supposedly support WeakRef's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef) I thought I could make a Map that holds WeakRefs to my tree elements and then simply `deref()` and see if the elements are still around. I tried to test this but it doesn't seem to work. My minimal test looks like this:

```js
const lookup = new Map();
let element = new Object({id:"someid", data: {}});

lookup.set(element.id, new WeakRef(element));
console.dir(lookup.get("someid").deref());
// as expected output is { id: 'someid', data: {} }

element = null;
console.log(element);
// as expected output is null

// simply calling global.gc() didn't work
// so i made this loop which allocates mem *and* calls global.gc() to
// force garbage collection
// problem: infinite loop because deref always returns the dereferenced
// value which should have gone since element was set to null

while (lookup.get("someid").deref()) {
  const a = new Array(1000);
  // enabled with --expose-gc in node
  global.gc();
}

console.dir(lookup.get("someid").deref());
```

As written above in the comment, the issue is that the loop never ends
because the deref call always returns a value despite the element var
being set to null.

Am I missing something here? If not and this is how it is supposed to work,
how can I achieve my goal of having a map of weak references (WeakMap is not
an option here, since I would have an O(n) cost of looking up an element by id)?.

Comment: I've never run it a need for this, but maybe I should have. Can you say more about the use-case for this? Why can't you just let the map go out of scope at the same time the elements themselves go our of scope as well, in which case the GC behavior would be the same.

Comment: The map itself will never go out of scope. It is in a singleton holding references to all active tree elements (or to some dynamic ones that are fetched from a service where the cost of fetching it would outweigh looking it up and re-using). At least this is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: If you are familiar with mobx-state-tree: it is similar to resolveIdentifier. Basically look up an element in a tree with O(1) instead of O(n) (tree is not binary, not sorted).  The thing with resolveIdenfier and their lookup map is: they know when the object dies and remove if from the lookup map. I thought I could handle it more "lazily".

Comment: So it's a cache, but you can't manually delete elements from the cache, because sometimes that's outside of your control? Is that the issue?

Comment: Well, I could of course hold a manual reference count but that would be a PITA because I would have to traverse the tree and its elements on adding, removing (elements can refer to others, etc.). Sure, manual reference count could be a thing. But it is error prone and I thought I could utilize WeakRefs for this purpose :-/ And now I am wondering whether I understood the WeakRefs in JS correctly.

Comment: I didn't mean reference counting. Just deleting the element from the cache. But perhaps the issue here is that it's a tree-cache, not a flat key-value cache?

Comment: It is key value, but: imagine you cache a file system in a "file browser", the nodes to your files. The nodes can refer/link to other nodes, folders can be open multiple times, etc. This means that I would have to manually count the references since when one "folder" is closed, it doesn't mean the cached value can go away.

Comment: "WeakMap is not an option here, since I would have an O(n) cost of looking up an element by id" What do you mean by this? I'm pretty sure they're O(1) lookup just like a regular Map. Some naive polyfills for older browsers are O(n) lookup, but that should be no problem if you're restricting yourself to browsers that support WeakRef anyway.

Comment: WeakMap has objects as keys, also WeakMap (keys) is not iterable. It's about looking up in the cache by id. Imagine you have a map with "someid" as key, with a weak reference to it. Now I load some object/tree from the network, I cannot use WeakMap because I would have to have the object for lookup, which I don't. Since I loaded the data from the network, all I have is the object's id, and this is why I meant WeakMap is not an option.

Comment: No you can't. Please read the documentation on WeakMap. WeakMap only accepts **objects** as keys, not primitive types. Also mentioned in the response to your answer by @jfriend00.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Just do `keyById = {someid: {}}` and then do `someWkMap.set(keyById['someid'], {...})`, and later do `someWkMap.get(keyById['someid'])`. This wastes some memory in `keyById`, but no worse than your original plan also wastes memory by leaving pairs of ids and WeakRefs in the Map.

Comment: Why do you care when the WeakRef gets garbage collected? On small pages the browser is probably really lazy about it, especially synchronously. If your goal is to do something when `deref()` eventually returns null, maybe you can use a `FinalizationRegistry`?

Comment: Regarding your keyById suggestion: WeakMap holds a weak reference to the **key** and a strong reference to the value. So, this won't work. The reason why I want to do this is because the project is handling a lot of nodes in an electron app, meaning the users will potentially have the app open for a whole day and memory will keep on growing. It's more of an app than a simple webpage. I don't care when the element held by the WeakRef get's garbage collected. I just want that it will. But my example shows that it apparently won't and this is a problem.

Comment: You're totally right, I understand now. But since the browser makes no promises about when a WeakRef will be collected, your test case doesn't really show that it's not working. On a page that does that in a long loop with lots of big objects, does the memory usage keep growing or eventually plateau?

Comment: Any memory usage test needs to pause (and do nothing) for some meaningful amount of time to be sure the GC does whatever it really wants to do.  Calling `global.gc()` is not necessarily sufficient in my experience.  I don't know what exactly `global.gc()` does, but it does not seem to do everything that an actual idle interpreter will do (like using a `setTimeout()` with nothing else going on before measuring.  And, then when you measure, you have to measure the in-use heap, not the total process memory as the total process memory will a a high water mark.

Comment: See my answer below.  The GC is just being lazy and calling `global.gc()` does not force its hand.  In my two tests, in node v14.15.0, it only fully GCs when I give it 10 seconds of idle time.  In previous experiments, I've also noticed that calling `global.gc()` does not fully run GC.

Comment: Just to set the record straight: `global.gc()` does run a full GC cycle, but for clearing WeakRefs, _per spec_ you need to return to the event loop (in addition to running a GC cycle).

Comment: Minor nit: `element = new Object({id:"someid", data: {}})` is needless duplication, just write `element = {id:"someid", data: {}}` instead.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have actually tried enclosing the test in nextTick, this didn't work either.

Comment: @jmrk It's actually the same (besides the {} being faster). But yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes: you're missing the notes in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef) you've linked to, for instance:

> If your code has just created a WeakRef for a target object, or has gotten a target object from a WeakRef's deref method, that target object will not be reclaimed until the end of the current JavaScript job (including any promise reaction jobs that run at the end of a script job). That is, you can only "see" an object get reclaimed between turns of the event loop.

And of course:

> **Avoid where possible**
> Correct use of WeakRef takes careful thought, and it's best avoided if possible. It's also important to avoid relying on any specific behaviors not guaranteed by the specification. When, how, and whether garbage collection occurs is down to the implementation of any given JavaScript engine.

That said, achieving your goal is totally possible; your test case is just too simple (in light of the notes quoted above) to show it. Here's a fixed version:

```
const lookup = new Map();

(function () {
  let element = { id: "someid", data: {} };
  lookup.set(element.id, new WeakRef(element));
  element = null;

  console.log(lookup.get("someid").deref());

  setTimeout(() => {
    global.gc();
    console.log(lookup.get("someid").deref());
  }, 0);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The real issue here is that calling `global.gc()` does not run a full GC pass.  In my tests below, only when I allowed 10 seconds of idle time did I get full GC.

Here are some observations about your specific code.  If I add a single `await delay(5000)` pause in the GC, then your object is still not GCed before the `while` loop.  But, if I add two `await delay(5000)` statements or one `await delay(10000)` statement, it is GCed before the `while` loop.  So, the GC is clearly timing sensitive and calling `global.gc()` is apparently not a full run of GC.  For example, here's a version of your code where the weakref is GCed!

```
function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

async function run() {

    const lookup = new Map();
    let element = new Object({ id: "someid", data: {} });

    lookup.set(element.id, new WeakRef(element));
    console.dir(lookup.get("someid").deref());
    // as expected output is { id: 'someid', data: {} }

    element = null;
    await delay(10000);
    console.log(element);
    // as expected output is null

    // if above is delay(5000), then it logs "in while loop"
    // if above is delay(10000), then it does NOT log "in while loop"
    // so the amount of time is important to allow the GC to do its thing
     
    while (lookup.get("someid").deref()) {
        console.log("in while loop");
        break;
    }

    console.dir(lookup.get("someid").deref());
}

run();
```

---

Before I discovered that your code would GC with a delay, I set out to just run an experiement to see whether a WeakRef works or not.  This is the code that showed (that with the right delays to allow full GC), the WeakRef does work in node v14.15.

Here's my test code:

```
// to make memory usage output easier to read
function addCommas(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;

    while (i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}

function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

function logUsage() {
    let usage = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log(`heapUsed: ${addCommas(usage.heapUsed)}`);
}

const numElements = 10000;
const lenArrays = 10000;

async function run() {

    const cache = new Map();
    const holding = [];

    function checkItem(n) {
        let item = cache.get(n).deref();
        console.log(item);
    }

    // fill all the arrays and the cache
    // and put everything into the holding array too
    let arr, element;
    for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        arr = new Array(lenArrays);
        arr.fill(i);
        element = { id: i, data: arr };

        // temporarily hold onto each element by putting a
        // full reference (not a weakRef) into an array
        holding.push(element);

        // add a weakRef to the Map
        cache.set(i, new WeakRef(element));
    }
    // clean up locals we don't need any more
    element = array = null;

    // should have a big Map holding lots of data
    // all items should still be available
    checkItem(numElements - 1);
    logUsage();

    await delay(5000);
    logUsage();

    // make whole holding array contents eligible for GC
    holding.length = 0;

    // pause for GC, then see if items are available
    // and what memory usage is
    await delay(5000);
    checkItem(0);
    checkItem(1);
    checkItem(numElements - 1);

    // count how many items are still in the Map
    let cnt = 0;
    for (const [index, item] of cache) {
        if (item.deref()) {
            ++cnt;
            console.log(`Index item ${index} still in cache`);
        }
    }
    console.log(`There are ${cnt} items that haven't be GCed in the map`);
    logUsage();
}

run();
```

And, the output I get is this:

```
{
  id: 9999,
  data: [
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    ... 9900 more items
  ]
}
heapUsed: 806,706,120
heapUsed: 806,679,456
undefined
undefined
undefined
There are 0 items that haven't be GCed in the map
heapUsed: 3,412,144
```

The two `undefined` lines in the output and the last heapUsed show that the objects wrapped in weakRef references did get GCed.

So, after enough of a time delay with nothing else for the interpreter to do, data with only a weakRef does appear to be GCed.  I don't know yet exactly why your example is not showing that except that my experience has shown that merely calling `global.gc()` does not necessarily do all the same GC that an actual idle interpreter will do.  So, I'd suggest you insert a legit pause (like I'm doing in my example) and see if you do eventually get the memory back.

---

P.S. I posted [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646525/why-is-last-iteration-of-variable-declared-in-for-loop-not-getting-garbage-colle) about a GC anomaly I discovered while working on this answer.

Comment: `global.gc` does run a full GC cycle. You don't need any second-long delays. However, to see WeakRefs get cleared, you do need a turn of the event loop (which is a side effect of interrupting an async function, as your `delay` does). See the MDN documentation, or my answer, for an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. However, I have accepted @jmrk's answer since it seems all I needed for the test was the setTimeout(..., 0) and it works just fine, meaning there really isn't a longer wait necessary for a full gc cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine (except for the while loop and `global.gc()`, of course). If you run this test page in Chrome, and you wait a while, eventually it logs in the console that many WeakRefs have indeed been garbage-collected: https://output.jsbin.com/momelej