# Why is last iteration of variable declared in for loop not getting garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8, weak-references

My question is whether this is a nodejs garbage collector bug?  Or is this somehow expected?

Running node v14.15.0 on Windows.

While working on an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644104/lookup-table-with-weak-references-in-javascript/67645980#67645980) involving WeakRef objects, I discovered a curious thing about garbage collection that seems like a possible bug.  An object assigned to a variable declared within a `for` loop is not getting garbage collected even after that `let` variable is out of scope of the `for` loop.  The variable of interest here is named `element` and here's the loop it is in.  It is just the object from the last iteration of the loop that is not getting GCed (the one that `element` last pointed to):

```
// fill all the arrays and the cache
// and put everything into the holding array too
for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    let arr = new Array(lenArrays);
    arr.fill(i);
    let element = { id: i, data: arr };

    // temporarily hold onto each element by putting a
    // full reference (not a weakRef) into an array
    holding.push(element);

    // add a weakRef to the Map
    cache.set(i, new WeakRef(element));
}
```

Then, a few lines of code later, we clear the array `holding` with this:

```
holding.length = 0;
```

You would think that after this loop is finished and after `holding` has been cleared, that all the values of `element` from that loop should be eligible for GC.  The only references to them any more are via `WeakRef` objects (which don't prevent GC).

And, indeed, if I let nodejs have some idle time, all the objects except the very last one created by the `for` loop are indeed GCed.  But, the last one is not.  If I add `element = null` to the end of the `for` loop, then that last one then does get GCed.  So, somehow nodejs is not clearing the refcnt on the variable that `element` last pointed to, even though `element` is now out of scope.

So, you can see the entire code here (you can drop this into a file and run it in nodejs yourself):

```
'use strict';

// to make memory usage output easier to read
function addCommas(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;

    while (i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}

function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

function logUsage() {
    let usage = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log(`heapUsed: ${addCommas(usage.heapUsed)}`);
}

const numElements = 10000;
const lenArrays = 10000;

async function run() {

    const cache = new Map();
    const holding = [];

    function checkItem(n) {
        let item = cache.get(n).deref();
        console.log(item);
    }

    // fill all the arrays and the cache
    // and put everything into the holding array too
    for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        let arr = new Array(lenArrays);
        arr.fill(i);
        let element = { id: i, data: arr };

        // temporarily hold onto each element by putting a
        // full reference (not a weakRef) into an array
        holding.push(element);

        // add a weakRef to the Map
        cache.set(i, new WeakRef(element));
    }

    // should have a big Map holding lots of data
    // all items should still be available
    checkItem(numElements - 1);
    logUsage();

    await delay(5000);
    logUsage();

    // make whole holding array contents eligible for GC
    holding.length = 0;

    // pause for GC, then see if items are available
    // and what memory usage is
    await delay(5000);
    checkItem(0);
    checkItem(1);
    checkItem(numElements - 1);

    // count how many items are still in the Map
    let cnt = 0;
    for (const [index, item] of cache) {
        if (item.deref()) {
            ++cnt;
            console.log(`Index item ${index} still in cache`);
        }
    }
    console.log(`There are ${cnt} items that haven't been GCed in the map`);
    logUsage();
}

run();
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
{
  id: 9999,
  data: [
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    ... 9900 more items
  ]
}
heapUsed: 805,544,472
heapUsed: 805,582,072
undefined
undefined
{
  id: 9999,
  data: [
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,
    ... 9900 more items
  ]
}
Index item 9999 still in cache
There are 1 items that haven't been GCed in the map
heapUsed: 3,490,168
```

The two `undefined` lines are expected.  The second logged output of the id:9999 object is not expected.  It should also be `undefined`.  And, finding that id:9999 object still in the cache is not expected.  It should have been eligible for GC.

---

One possible theory is that the V8 optimizer is pulling `element` out of the `for` loop to avoid having to create it over and over within the loop, but then not making it eligible for GC after the loop is done - essentially hoisting it to the higher scope.

Another theory is that GC isn't always block scope granularity.

Bug or not?

Comment: Don't forget to tag the question [v8] so that @jmrk will take a look :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Thx.  I didn't know that was a thing to do.

Comment: Looks like compiler based loop optimization with hoisting the element variable.
Try to declare a element variable in the upper scope and use element = undefined; after the loop. That should make the element unaccessable and make it gcable.
If that is not working than the WeakMap is not implemented correctly or you really discovered a bug.

Comment: @KaiLehmann: no, loop optimization has nothing to do with it. (Also, you may want to read the documentation for `WeakRef` before making claims about implementation correctness).

Comment: @jmrk As I said "it looks like". I said not "this is definitly the correct solution." But sorry I tried to help. You're absolutely right. Guessing things is descructive.

Comment: @KaiLehmann that's an extreme overreaction against somebody trying to help as well...

Comment: @KaiLehmann - Your suggested change does make the issue go away so the unexpected behavior is related to the loop variable and/or the block scope.  I still don't know why the GC doesn't clean that loop variable up on its own while the parent scope is still active.

Comment: @jfriend00: I've added another paragraph with more detail to address your "still don't know" concern.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug. I agree that the behavior here appears odd at first glance, but as the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef) puts it:

> It's also important to avoid relying on any specific behaviors not guaranteed by the specification. When, how, and whether garbage collection occurs is down to the implementation of any given JavaScript engine.

While it's (of course) true that `element` is out of scope after the loop as far as JavaScript language semantics are concerned, there is no guarantee/promise/specification that an object that a `let`-variable in a loop (or other block) pointed to is eligible for garbage collection immediately at the end of that block. The engine is free to e.g. internally allocate a stack slot for this variable that'll only get cleared at the end of the current function; and stack slots are generally considered "roots" by the GC, i.e. they keep alive what they point to.

It *would* be a bug if failure to free unreachable objects led to unbounded memory growth until an OOM crash occurs. But that's not the case here: it's *one* object that sticks around until the end of the function, no matter whether you set `numElements` to 1 or 10 or 10000.

Side note: there's no need to sleep for five seconds to get a GC run; Node's `global.gc()` is just fine, you just also need to return to the event loop in order to see WeakRefs get cleared (as the MDN doc also points out).

---

EDIT to add:
The specific reason why in this particular case the last `element` sticks around is because *unoptimized* code/bytecode simply allocates a stack slot for each local variable. It doesn't bother nulling out that slot before the function returns, so the object that the stack slot refers to will be kept alive until the function returns. This is normally (without WeakRefs) unobservable, and just one of many tradeoffs between execution speed, startup latency, memory consumption, CPU/power consumption, code complexity, and/or other metrics that an engine makes. These internal details are intentionally not documented, because they can change at any time, and nobody should rely on them (as the MDN documentation points out).
If you force the function `run` to get optimized after a while, the optimizing compiler will spend the time to do proper live range analysis, which typically causes stack slots to get reused for different things as execution of the function progresses, and (at least in this case) has the consequence that the object will actually get garbage-collected sooner.
That said, while I understand your curiosity, I'd like to emphasize again: the internal details really don't matter. What exactly happens inside a JS engine highly depends on the overall scenario, and of course changes depending on which engine and which version of it you're running.

Comment: Can you tell us more about "stack slots" in V8? Are they re-used or is there one slot per variable (i.e. does `(function(){ { let a; } { let b; } { let c; } }())` create three slots or just one)?

Comment: "It depends" (e.g. the interpreter may or may not act differently from the optimizing compiler in this regard). Stack frame size is generally considered an unpredictable implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but I also thought stack slots would only be relevant as GC roots for code that is currently executing, i.e. on the stack. Are they also used in suspended generators and async functions? How do stack slots relate to lexical environment objects that closures are created over?

Comment: Suspended generators (and async functions, which _are_ generators) also must keep their stack contents alive, otherwise they'd crash if they are resumed after a GC cycle. -- When a closure references a variable from its outer scope, then that variable is generally allocated in a "Context" object on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: Ah, I had always assumed that coroutines would serialise their stack contents into such a context object upon suspension and restore the values to the stack upon resumption - and, actually, would keep only those values that are again referenced later in the function, similar to the scope analysis done for closures. Just taking the entire stack frame is of course simpler and faster; with the minor annoyance that it sometimes uses more memory than necessary and keeps more values than expected.