# Do you need to nullify variables at the end of Node.js functions to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, memory-leaks

so I'm trying to find a memory leak in an app I've deployed to Heroku. I use express post requests in most if not all of my functions so I think there's some fundamental issue I'm missing here. Looking at the 'Closures' section of this link (https://betterprogramming.pub/the-4-types-of-memory-leaks-in-node-js-and-how-to-avoid-them-with-the-help-of-clinic-js-part-1-3f0c0afda268), it seems like you have to nullify variables to deallocate the memory they take up. Here is my function:

```
async function HelperFunction() {
  const client = await pool.connect()
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    let var0 = []
    let currentDate = new Date()
    let date = ("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let month = ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    let currentTimestamp = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
    try {
      await client.query('BEGIN')
      const res = await client.query(querySQLFunction, [currentTimestamp]);
      for (row of res.rows) {
          let jsonObject = {
            var1: row.var1,
            var2 : row.var2,
            var3 : Number(row.var3),
            var4 : Number(row.var4),
            var5 : 0
          }
          var0.push(jsonObject)
        }
      await client.query('COMMIT')
    } catch(err) {
      await client.query('ROLLBACK')
      console.log(err)
    } finally {
      client.release()
      resolve(var0)
    }
  })
}
```

So for example, in the above function, do I have to set all the lets to null in the 'finally' block? Also, if I define functions inside other functions:

```
async function otherFunction() {
    const foo = async (page) => {
        //await query some stuff
    }
    //nullification of foo here?
}
```

do I have to set the const's to null before the function is over?

Comment: Related? [Why is last iteration of variable declared in for loop not getting garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67646525)

Comment: I'm not sure the memory leak is just coming from the for loop though--I have a suspicion it might be from the let variables above the for loop as well. @VLAZ

Comment: No, you don't. You may need to do this if a function modified variables in parent scope, which is not the case. The code contains promise constructor antipattern, but I don't think it can cause a leak

Comment: @EstusFlask Okay good to know, thank you for your help! I'll keep searching for the root issue.

Comment: Unrelated, but [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: "*it seems like you have to nullify variables to deallocate the memory they take up*" - no, you don't. You just have to make sure they go out of scope (of anything that stays alive). To find your memory leak, make heap snapshots and look at what objects are retained unexpectedly.

Comment: @Bergi After reading about promise antipattern, it seems like you can just return the function instead of using try/catch. So what exactly would that look like in this case? (I'm also assuming that the anti pattern is evident in HelperFunction(), but I'm having a tough time relating examples here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) to my code.

Comment: Yes, you should just remove the line `return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {` and  replace `resolve(var0)` by `return var0`. As for what the problem is, consider what happens if `client.release()` throws or you have typo in the lines before the `try`.

Comment: @Bergi Great, thank you--looking at my code now, anti pattern is evident through my entire backend. As a side note, is anti pattern just inefficient or can it cause actual errors?

Comment: Yes, it causes actual problems - when an error happens (in the wrong place), it doesn't reject the returned promise but causes an unhandled promise rejection (of the promise returned by the `async function`).